How to maximize $l_1$ norm?
I have a problem of the form
\begin{align*}
\max \sum |a_i^T x + c_i| \text{ s.t. } x \in S
\end{align*}
My idea was to introduce auxiliary variables to remove the absolute value in the objective and then solve it with the help of KKT-conditions. However this approach seems to only work for minimization problems not maximization problems. How could one approach solving this problem?

There's KKT conditions for subgradients, i.e. a generalization of gradient. There's also ways to get rid of the absolute sign with other tricks, e.g. notice that $\sqrt{x^2 + p^2}\rightarrow |x| $ as $p \rightarrow 0$. Depends on the problem and your background. Are you allowed to solve this using numerical methods?

Thank you for the comment! Ideally I would like to have a formal solution, so to be able to give an explicit formula for $x$. But if this is not feasible, then I would of course be open for alternatives.

@samabu What is the definition of S?

$S$ is a set defined by $x^Ty = 0$ for a given vector $y$ and $f(x)=0$ where $f$ is a quadratic function.

@samabu Your comment causes more questions than answering my question. You introduce much more conditions and variables than someone can guess from your question.

I thought it might be easier to have as many option as possible by being general with the set. I can also adjust the question if preferred.
